# How to Search a file in QDir

Tags: macos, qt, qdir, qfileinfo

I am developing an Application for MAC OS X. In which I have to find files in folder. Problem is that I want to give comfort, to user, to search a file by entering a `QString`. This QString may be the exact name of file or a text contain in the file name.Suppose the file name is `"mysamplefile.txt"`. So if user enter either `'my'` ; `'mysample'` ; `'samplefile'` ; `'mysamplefile'` or `'mysamplefile.txt'`. In all cases I want to get the `QFileInfo` for that file. I also give checkbox option `'Match Case'` or `'Ignore case'` to the user to get `fileinfo`. I have a `QStringList` for the `strings` that user want to search and I also have a `QStringList` of the locations selected by the user. So I want to search each string name(from `QStringList strSearchFileName`) in every Path(`QStringList searchingdirectorylist`). And I want to make a final `QFileInfoList` for all files after the searching process.

```
void MainWindowWipe::onSearchingProcess(QStringList strSearchFileName, QStringList searchingdirectorylist)
{       
    for(int i=0; i<strSearchFileName.size();i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<searchingdirectorylist.size();j++)
        {
            QDir dir(searchingdirectorylist[j]);
            dir.setNameFilters(QStringList(strSearchFileName[i]));
            dir.setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::NoSymLinks);

            QFileInfoList fileList = dir.entryInfoList();
            for (int k=0; k<fileList.count(); k++)
            {
                QString temp = "";
                temp = fileList[k].absoluteFilePath();

            }

            dir.setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::NoSymLinks);
            QStringList dirList = dir.entryList();
            QStringList newList;    
            for (int l=0; l<dirList.size(); ++l)
            {
                QString newPath = QString("%1/%2").arg(dir.absolutePath()).arg(dirList.at(i));
                newList<<newPath;

                onSearchingProcess(strSearchFileName,newList);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

This function is not working for me this work only when if I search only one file with exact name. But I want to search  multiple files with not exact name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through all the files and folders using a recursive function (or use the iterator). On each iteration you can use the `QString::contains()` to find out if the file's name contains the target string. Save each matching file name in a list.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDirIterator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString targetStr = "init"; // What we search for
    QFileInfoList hitList; // Container for matches
    QString directory = "D:/python/"; // Where to search
    QDirIterator it(directory, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);

    // Iterate through the directory using the QDirIterator
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        QString filename = it.next();
        QFileInfo file(filename);

        if (file.isDir()) { // Check if it's a dir
            continue;
        }

        // If the filename contains target string - put it in the hitlist
        if (file.fileName().contains(targetStr, Qt::CaseInsensitive)) {
            hitList.append(file);
        }
    }

    foreach (QFileInfo hit, hitList) {
        qDebug() << hit.absoluteFilePath();
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```